# Print type object in typescript

Tags: typescript

Is there an option in typescript to take a custom type, say:

```
type myCustomType = {
    type1: string
    type2: number
}
```

and use it in a variable? say

```
const theTypeIWantToPrint = getTypeAsString(myCustomType.type2)
console.log(theTypeIWantToPrint) // prints "number"
```

or just plainly do `console.log(getTypeAsString(myCustomType.type2))`

Comment: You mean variable in type `myCustomType`  e.g: `var f: myCustomType = {type1:'string', type2:2};`? and then `getTypeAsString(f.type2)` ??

Comment: no, I mean printing the actual type, meaning the string "number" for `getTypeAsString(myCustomType.type2)`

Comment: Without instantiate?

Comment: Yes, just to print the type or to stringify the type and assign the type to a variable

Comment: TypeScript types don't exist at runtime (other than a small runtime aspect to enums). There's an API for the compiler that might let you output this information somewhere where you could then use it, but it'll be custom.

Comment: @T.J.Crowder Thanks, which API is that?

Comment: @user2078716 - I haven't used it. A search for "typescript compiler api" turned up [this](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/wiki/Using-the-Compiler-API) as the first hit.

Answer (score -4):

I am not sure if this is the one that you want like typescript union type?
Something like this.

```
type myCustomType = string | number;
```

You can either pass string or number to this type.
And check if it's number or string like

```
console.log(typeof test); // if string/number then do something
```

Comment: That's the thing, I don't want to do `typeof test` which is the type of an object `test` of type `myCustomType`, but to print `myCustomType.type2` and to get the string "number"